# Is there any way to grow a box shadow width independantly from height?

Tags: html, css

`box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px;` puts 5 pixels of all each side.

I have a centered div that spans the height of the view port styled with a box-shadow like this `box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0;` for the layered illusion, but because the div stops at the top and bottom of the browser, the corners of the shadow show. This is ill desired. I think if I could somehow grow the height (but not the width) of the shadow, I could achieve the exact appearance I have currently, minus the curved corners.

https://jsfiddle.net/nu4j0htf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pseudo-element, like `:before` you can create a box shadow of different dimensions that your primary element. However, my implementation causes vertical scrolling that needs to be remedied.

https://jsfiddle.net/nu4j0htf/1/

```
body {
 overflow: hidden; /* added */
}

/* removed box-shadow from .backDrop and added this */
.backDrop:before {
  content:'';
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 black;
 position: absolute;
 height: 120vh;
 width: 75vw;
}
```

If you need vertical scrolling on your page, you will need to think of a different solution.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid vertical scrolling for now, so I'll worry about that later. However I noticed that the top of the shadow hasn't been fixed. you can change the shadow to white to see it more clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I just made a quick example to show how it can be done. You can very easily just change the position of the pseudo-element by adding a `top` or `margin-top` or whatever else you want for your use-case.

Comment: Just realized I can also do `box-shadow: 0 -10 10px 0 black;` to the shadow in the pseudo-element.